# Fallout Shelter Losing Resources After game is Closed

Tags: fallout-shelter

So, I've been playing Fallout Shelter since it came out, and quite frankly I'm a little baffled as to how people get so far in the game. So far every vault I've had I've lost because of little thing I can't seem to get around. So, it's like this, I'll be playing upgrading my vault, collecting resources and what not. Then I'll have to do something where I can't play like go to bed or something, I've heard that the game runs in the background even after I close it for a few minutes and will notify me if my production rooms are ready then stops. But when I get back in the game, all my resources are completely depleted, and my dwellers are dying and are sick. This is completely irreversable as the rate of my resources being depleted as I regain them is 5 to 1. Am I doing something wrong? Does this happen to everyone?

Comment: Note that the game itself mentions that it runs for a little while when you close the app (in my experience that amount of time is probably 2-4 minutes). This behavior apparently persists even if you [close the app manually](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201330): I have had it continue to give lock-screen banner notifications.

Answer (score 8):

The game does continue to run for a little while after you leave. This is to encourage players to play for extended periods of time instead of just quickly checking on their vaults. You need to make sure that you have enough resources to survive the period in which the game runs yet you aren't online.

I would check that you have enough storage. You might not even have the capacity to store enough resources to survive closing the game.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are completely logging out of the game??  Don't just click the game off. Go to the bottom right corner and click on the pip boy. The first option lets you log out. Click on the gears symbol then main menu. After that you can click out of the game and it won't keep running forever depleting all resources.

Answer (score 0):

The game sets a timer when you log off, for 3 minutes it will continue to run as if your still playing except ofcourse you cannot collect resources (i dont know if a mr.handy will collect for your during this time) and no attacks or disasters will happen.

After 3mins the resources also stop moving and the only things still running are the timers on your rooms, quests and wasteland explorers.